# R e PostgreSql - AND/OR e BEETWEN/NOT BEETWEN como ajudar na lógica?

Tags: r, postgresql, operador-lógico

Preciso pegar algumas informações do banco de dados postgreSQL através do R .

Entretanto, os filtros não estão baixando o que eu quero. Gostaria que baixasse apenas as cnaes de empresas com situação cadastral "2" e na data "02/2020". Como fiz, ele está puxando outras datas.

Segue exemplo:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
...
Cnae_selecionada <- dbGetQuery(con,"
                   SELECT *
                   FROM cnpj.cnae
                   WHERE 
                      (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 3700000 AND 3999999)
                   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 4900000 AND 5399999)
                   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 5500000 AND 5699999)
                   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 5800000 AND 6399999)
                   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 6600000 AND 6699999)
                   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 6800000 AND 7599999)
                   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 7700000 AND 8299999)
                   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 9200000 AND 9699999)
                   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 160000 AND 169999)
                   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 230000 AND 239999)
                   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 4520000 AND 4529999)
                   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 4543000 AND 4543999)
                   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 8550000 AND 8559999)
                   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 8590000 AND 8599999)
                   AND (cnae_fiscal NOT BETWEEN 6912000 AND 6912999)
                   AND (cnae_fiscal NOT BETWEEN 7010000 AND 7019999)
                   AND (cnae_fiscal NOT BETWEEN 8112000 AND 8112999)
                   AND (cnae_fiscal NOT BETWEEN 9400000 AND 9499999)
                   AND situacao_cadastral LIKE '2'AND data LIKE '%02/2020%'
                   ")
```

Tentei de algumas outras formas também, porém sem sucesso.

Comment: Verifique a prioridade dos operadores AND e OR. Talvez seja necessária uma parentização para a avaliação correta. No seu caso todos estes AND se aplicam apenas a `(cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 8590000 AND 8599999)` ou deveriam se aplicar a todas as faixas?

Comment: qual o tipo de dados do campo `data`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa separar as condições OR e AND, se elas estiverem alinhadas, qualquer OR que seja true, vai ignorar os outros AND. Use ( ) e separe todos os OR:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM cnpj.cnae
   WHERE 
   (
      (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 3700000 AND 3999999)
   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 4900000 AND 5399999)
   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 5500000 AND 5699999)
   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 5800000 AND 6399999)
   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 6600000 AND 6699999)
   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 6800000 AND 7599999)
   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 7700000 AND 8299999)
   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 9200000 AND 9699999)
   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 160000 AND 169999)
   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 230000 AND 239999)
   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 4520000 AND 4529999)
   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 4543000 AND 4543999)
   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 8550000 AND 8559999)
   OR (cnae_fiscal BETWEEN 8590000 AND 8599999) 
   )

   AND (cnae_fiscal NOT BETWEEN 6912000 AND 6912999)
   AND (cnae_fiscal NOT BETWEEN 7010000 AND 7019999)
   AND (cnae_fiscal NOT BETWEEN 8112000 AND 8112999)
   AND (cnae_fiscal NOT BETWEEN 9400000 AND 9499999)
   AND situacao_cadastral = '2' AND  data LIKE '%02/2020%'
```

A data, salvo se estiver no formato de texto, você pode usar:

```
date_trunc('day', data) between '01/02/2020' and '29/02/2020'
```

Comment: Perfeito ! Obrigado ! E a data está em forma de texto mesmo, com um charactere a mais, inclusive.